# Best performance solution to display list of Post in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, rerender

I am current doing on a Flutter Facebook clone project and I use BLOC pattern for my project. I have PostBloc class which convert PostFetch event (fetch list of posts) to PostState (PostList: list of posts). Then I have Post ListView and map to list of PostContainer stateless widget. But I will face to a problem. If I do like a Post, I have three choices:

1. Keep the same Post is a stateless widget, once I do like a Post, I call API updatePost(postID). And I update PostList state of Bloc then immediately causes rerender screen of list of posts.
2. Convert a Post to BLOC, it owns PostDetailState, once I do like a Post, it updates PostDetail state and call API updatePost(postID). And no update PostList state because this will not rerender total screen list of posts. Once the app reloads, app will call API get list of updated posts. In this approach, I whether if some situations like scroll down, that Post state is keeped persistent? And BLOC inside BLOC is valid?
3. Conver a Post to stateful widget, once I like a Post, it only update the local state of that Post. Because I don't use BLOC, I cann't call API direct in that Post widget. I only call API updatePost(postID) via parent of that Post widget which is ListView Post widget. When I have called API done, from now, I have two choices: first is no update PostList state, second is update PostList  state. In this situations, which choice is better?

Three above approach I have thought about displaying the posts screen. What is the best approach to do?

Comment: I want to addon your 3rd option 
1. you have to update the count locally in bloc 
2. After the count is updated you have to call the api of update post .
3. whatever result is coming like count and islike = true/false you have to update again for like and comment

Comment: i've done this type of code in my app if you interested to show then let me know

Comment: 3rd option: "When I have called API done, from now, I have two choices: first is no update PostList state,  second is update PostList state". Which choice you suggested me?

Comment: In state you have list of post right --> so you have to find the item which item is like in the list --> first update in model for single item locally and emit list--> same after api call

Comment: emit list of post (update PostList state at BLOC) will rerender all screen of posts. This can cause low performance just by one post?

Comment: My list in state --> state.list --> when i like --> find the which item is like on list --> after updation emit the list 

- If you emit the whole list with one item bloc is notifying you only one item is updated not whole list

Comment: Thank you, but I see this approach quite same as 1st appoarch. Why we decide to use Stateful instead Stateless widget?

Comment: You can use stateless as well